# Testing in-app purchase

Tags: ios, xcode

I use this code to process my in-app purchase:

```
#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            {

            // show wait view here
           // statusLabel.text = @"Processing...";

                }
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                {

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view and unlock feature 2
           // statusLabel.text = @"Done!";
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                message:@"You have unlocked Feature 2!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [tmp show];



            NSError *error = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@"IAPStoreSave" andPassword:@"whatever" forServiceName:kStoredData updateExisting:YES error:&error];

            // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and

                    [self.lockImage removeFromSuperview];

            // do other thing to enable the features

                    }
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
           // statusLabel.text = @"";

                }
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            {

            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
           // statusLabel.text = @"Purchase Error!";

            }
            break;

        default:
            {

                 }
            break;
    }
}
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

// remove wait view here
    // statusLabel.text = @"";

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count>0) {
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.app.ID"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


} else {
    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                        message:@"No products to purchase"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];

}


}
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
 {

}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
       NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

And start it in this way:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.app.ID"]];


            request.delegate = self;

            [request start];
```

In my itunes connect I set up the in-app with the product ID I have entered, and the status is "ready to submit", and it also says: "Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary." When i start the request, the alert NO PRODUCT AVAILABLE always show up. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that bundle ID is the same as the app on Itunes Connect? Second to check is app provisioning profile (if it handles IAP) - I think this could be the reason. Let me know.